# Using __attribute__ with typedef

Tags: c++, visual-c++, macros, g++, typedef

Apologies if the question seems too obvious or simple. Unfortunately, after going through a bunch of threads and googling about typedef coupled with **attribute** prefix, I am still not able to it figure out.

I have a following snippet of code in a (supposedly) portable app -

```
#ifdef WIN32
#define MY_PREFIX __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MY_PREFIX __attribute__((visibility("default")))
#endif

typedef MY_PREFIX bool some_func(void);
```

So my question is this - 
1) What is that typedef exactly doing? 
2) The code compiles fine on VS2008, but on G++ (gcc-4.1), I get a warning 
   "‘visibility’ attribute ignored" 
   Is there any way I can remove that warning? (Omitting -Wattributes is not an option)

Thanks!

Comment: That doesn't look like a typedef that makes sense. Did you mean `typedef (MY_PREFIX *some_func)(void)`? (Also, `(void)` in C++ is an anachronism)

Comment: I understand that its trying to define a function pointer. And unfortunately, the weird looking typedef does compile on VS2008. :-/

Comment: @sskanitk: No. It is not a function pointer. It is a *function* type.

Comment: @AndreyT, O OK - thanks. So a function type should still be able to use  __attribute__, rite?

Answer (score 9):

AFAIK in GCC `visibility` attribute for function type cannot be "wrapped" into a typedef-ed type. The compiler assumes that this `visibility` attribute applies to the typedef-name itself. And GCC does not support `visibility` for typedef names (and it is not what you need anyway).

I'd say that instead of trying to wrap the `declspec`/`attribute` into the typedef, it should be specified explicitly at the point of function declaration. As in

```
#ifdef WIN32
#define MY_PREFIX __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MY_PREFIX __attribute__((visibility("default")))
#endif

typedef bool some_func(void);

MY_PREFIX some_func foo; // <- actual declaration
```

This will, of course, make is less clean, since instead of specifying `MY_PREFIX` once inside the typedef it should now be specified in every function declaration. But that's probably the only way to make it work, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Ok - thanks for the explanation. Specifying attribute after the function declaration did not work - same warning is thrown again.

Comment: @sskanitk: Yes, I noticed that too. You can specify attributes before and after. Both ways are valid, with different meanings.

Comment: I'm surprised you can't specify visibility for typedefs, but you can for a struct/class.  It seems like a double standard that types have linkage in C++, but you can't specify linkage for types defined through typedefs.